# How many 4 digit numbers are divisible by 29 such that their digit sum is also 29?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, recreational-mathematics

How many $4$ digit numbers are divisible by $29$ such that their digit sum is also $29$?

Well, answer is $5$ but what is the working and how did they get it?

Comment: please dont share results by computer program and excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the digits be$b,c,d,29-b-c-d$

As $0\le b,c,d\le9,0<b+c+d\le27<29$

Now, $$(29-b-c-d)+10b+100c+1000d=29+9b+99c+999d\equiv-20b+12c-16d$$

We need  $29\mid(5b-3c+4d)\equiv-24b-3c+33d\iff29\mid(c+8b-11d)$

For $29\mid(8b-11d)\implies8b-11d=(29k-c)(11\cdot3-8\cdot4)$

$\iff8(b+116k-4c)=11(87k+d-3c)\iff b+116k=11m+4c$

$\iff b\equiv5k+4c\pmod{11}$ and $d\equiv3c+k\pmod{11}$

Test for $c;0\le c\le9$ ensuring $0\le b,c,d\le9$ and $b+c+d\ge20$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full solution of the problem:

Let
$$(a,b,c,29-a-b-c)$$
be the decimal representation of such a number, and write $\equiv$ for equivalence modulo the prime $29$. We want $999a+99b+9c\equiv0$, or
$$13 a+12b+9c\equiv0\ .\tag{1}$$
Put $4b+3c=:r$. Then $(1)$ implies $13a+3r\equiv0$, which is satisfied by $a=2$, $r=1$, hence enforces
$$a\equiv2r\equiv 8b+6c\ .\tag{2}$$
We now have to determine the solutions of $(2)$ that in addition satisfy the constraints
$$a\in[1\>..\>9],\quad b,c\in[0\>..\>9],\quad 20\leq a+b+c\leq27\ .\tag{3}$$
This implies $b+c\geq11$, hence $b\geq2$, so that we can conclude that
$$70\leq 8b+6c\leq 126\ .$$
There are only the multiples $3\cdot29=87$ and $4\cdot 29=116$ near this range. In view of $(2)$ we therefore have to find the pairs $(b,c)$ with
$$88\leq 8b+6c\leq 96, \quad{\rm resp.,}\quad 118\leq 8b+6c\leq124\tag{4}$$ that lead to an $a$ such that the last constraint $(3)$ is satisfied. The first of the ranges $(4)$ contains the pairs
$$(9,4), \  (9,3), \ (8,5), \ (8,4), \ (7,6), \ (6,8), \ (6,7), \ (5,9), \ (5,8)\ ,$$
and the second range contains the pairs
$$(9,8), \ (8,9)\ .$$
For each of these pairs $(b,c)$ we now compute $a$ by means of $(2)$, and retain the triples $(a,b,c)$ for which the last condition $(3)$ is satisfied. These are the triples
$$(9,9,4), \ (7,8,5), \ (9,6,8), \ (7,5,9), \ (4,9,8)\ .$$
From these triples we then obtain the five numbers
$$9947, \ 7859, \ 9686, \ 7598, \ 4988$$
fulfilling the given conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a different take on things, in order for a number to be a multiple of $29$ and have digit sum congruent to $2$ mod $9$, the number must be of the form

$$29(9k+1)=261k+29$$

For the number to have four digits, we need $1000\le261k+29\le9999$, which requires $4\le k\le38$.

Now for the digit sum to be not just congruent to $2$ mod $9$ but actually *equal* to $29$, we cannot have any $0$'s or $1$'s among the four digits, and if there's a $2$ then the other three digits must be $9$'s. Therefore, we cannot have $k\equiv1$ or $2$ mod $10$, nor, since $261$ does not divide $9992-29$, can we have $k\equiv3$ mod $10$; also,  we need $2999\le261k+29$, which by itself requires $12\le k$. At this point we're left with $19$ possible values of $k$:

$$14,15,16,17,18,19,20\\24,25,26,27,28,29,30\\34,35,36,37,38$$

The values that work turn out to be $k=19$, $29$, $30$, $37$, and $38$. These correspond to the numbers $4988$, $7598$, $7859$, $9686$, and $9947$ found by Christian Blatter, whose approach boiled things down to checking just $11$ possibilities instead of the $19$ listed here. I wonder if some hybrid of the two approaches might improve at least on mine if not both.

Added later: It occurs to me it's possible to winnow the list of $k$'s by about a third without too much effort.  If $k$ ends in $6$ or less, then $261k+29$ ends in $5$ or less, which means the first three digits must sum to at least $24$. The smallest such number is $6990$, from which it follows that $k\ge27$. This eliminates $k=14$, $15$, $16$, $24$, $25$, and $26$. This leaves only $13$ values of $k$ to check, which is closer to Christian's tally.

Answer (score 1):

Given the $4$-digit number $\overline{abcd}$, the sum of digits being divisible by $29$ implies:
$$a+b+c+d=29,$$
because: $29<4\cdot 9<58$.

$\overline{abcd}$ is being divisible by $29$ implies:
$$1000a+100b+10c+d\equiv 14a+13b+10c+d\equiv 0\pmod{29}.$$
Hence:
$$\begin{cases} \ \ \ \ a+\ \ \ \ b+\ \ \ \ c+d=29 \\
14a+13b+10c+d=29n\end{cases}.$$
Multiply the first by $14$ and subtract the second:
$$b+4c+13d=29(14-n),9\le n<14,$$
because: $9+4\cdot 9+13\cdot 9=162<29\cdot 6=174$.

It is easy to check ($2\le b,c,d\le 9$):
$$\begin{align}&n=9 \Rightarrow b+4c+13d=145 \\
& \ \ \ d=9 \Rightarrow (b,c)=\color{red}{(4,6)}; (8,5);\\
&\ \ \ d=8 \Rightarrow (b,c)=(5,9); (9,8); \\
&\ \ \ (b,c,d)=(8,5,9), (5,9,8), (9,8,8);\\
&n=10 \Rightarrow b+4c+13d=116 \\
&\ \ \ d=8 \Rightarrow  (b,c)=\color{red}{(4,2)};\\
&\ \ \ d=7 \Rightarrow (b,c)=\color{red}{(5,5)}; (9,4);\\
&\ \ \ d=6 \Rightarrow (b,c)=\color{red}{(2,9)}; (6,8);\\
&\ \ \ (b,c,d)=(9,4,7), (6,8,6);\\
&n=11 \Rightarrow b+4c+13d=87 \\
&\ \ \ d=5 \Rightarrow  (b,c)=\color{red}{(2,5)}; \color{red}{(6,4)};\\
&\ \ \ d=4 \Rightarrow (b,c)=\color{red}{(3,8)}; \color{red}{(5,7)}; \color{red}{(9,6)}.
\end{align}$$
Hence:
$$\overline{abcd}=7859; 7598; 4988; 9947; 9686.$$

Comment: Nice approach! But why are those the *only* answers? E.g., what happens for $n=11$, $12$ and $13$?

Comment: @BarryCipra, they are empty and can be quickly verified. E.g., for $n=11$, the sum is $87$ and $2\le d\le 6$.

Comment: My interest here, as you can see in my answer, is in getting an idea of how many individual cases actually need to be looked at.  In addition to the "missing" cases $n=11$, $12$, and $13$, I'm not sure how you went about culling $n=9$ down to three possibilities and $n=10$ down to two. The equation $b+4c+13d=145$, for example, has quite a few more solutions with $0\le b,c,d\le9$ than the three that give a value for $a$ when back into the original pair of equations.

Comment: @BarryCipra, note that it is $2\le b,c,d\le 9$, because $a+b+c+d=29= 2+9\cdot 3$. I stated all possible cases and the ones in red are rejected by checking the values of $a$. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot, I had rejected digits $0$ and $1$ as well! (You might consider adding asterisks or something to the color coding to indicate non-solution $(b,c)$ pairs, for the benefit of readers who are colorblind.)